# Algo for 4-week rolling date calcs?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

I have a system in which I need to be able to calculate the week number and day number from any Monday to the current date. Weeks can only be 1-4, then it starts over. So, if we are 5 weeks from the "Monday start date", then we're actually on Week #1 again. Days can only be 0-6. 1 = Monday, etc. Start date must always be a Monday, but it can be any Monday of any month, any year, etc.

Today is `Friday, March 22, 2024`. If my start date is `Monday, March 18, 2024`, then the expected outcome is this:

```
Week=1
Day=5 (because today is Friday)
```

If the start date is `Monday, December 4, 2023`, then:

```
Week=4
Day=5 (because today is Friday)
```

So I built a function to calculate all this, but when the start date is more than 4 weeks back, the calculation is wrong, and for obvious reasons. Consider:

The function `DateTest()` has 3 input params:

1. Start Date
2. Expected week #
3. Expected day #

Notes:

1. All date calcs are relative to the start date (passed into the function) and today's date (Friday, March 22, 2024).
2. I calculated params 2 and 3 (expected week # and expected day #) by looking at a calendar and brute-force coming up with the right answer.

Here are the function calls:

```
DateTest("2023-12-04", 4, 5);
DateTest("2023-12-11", 3, 5);
DateTest("2023-12-18", 2, 5);
DateTest("2023-12-25", 1, 5);
DateTest("2024-01-01", 4, 5);
DateTest("2024-01-08", 3, 5);
DateTest("2024-01-15", 2, 5);
DateTest("2024-01-22", 1, 5);
DateTest("2024-01-29", 4, 5);
DateTest("2024-02-05", 3, 5);
DateTest("2024-02-12", 2, 5);
DateTest("2024-02-19", 1, 5);
DateTest("2024-02-26", 4, 5);
DateTest("2024-03-04", 3, 5);
DateTest("2024-03-11", 2, 5);
DateTest("2024-03-18", 1, 5);
```

And here are the results from the above function calls, all aligned in sequence:

```
2023-12-04 - Week - Actual: 16, Expected: 4, Diff: 12
2023-12-11 - Week - Actual: 15, Expected: 3, Diff: 12
2023-12-18 - Week - Actual: 14, Expected: 2, Diff: 12
2023-12-25 - Week - Actual: 13, Expected: 1, Diff: 12
2024-01-01 - Week - Actual: 12, Expected: 4, Diff: 8
2024-01-08 - Week - Actual: 11, Expected: 3, Diff: 8
2024-01-15 - Week - Actual: 10, Expected: 2, Diff: 8
2024-01-22 - Week - Actual: 9, Expected: 1, Diff: 8
2024-01-29 - Week - Actual: 8, Expected: 4, Diff: 4
2024-02-05 - Week - Actual: 7, Expected: 3, Diff: 4
2024-02-12 - Week - Actual: 6, Expected: 2, Diff: 4
2024-02-19 - Week - Actual: 5, Expected: 1, Diff: 4
2024-02-26 - SUCCESS
2024-03-04 - SUCCESS
2024-03-11 - SUCCESS
2024-03-18 - SUCCESS
```

Note: When the week and day match, it simply says SUCCESS. I am only showing WEEK data because the day # matches in all cases.

When you look at the results, you will immediately see that expected week # vs. actual week # brings a simple and obvious difference pattern. I need to perform a bit of math to make the week number always correct. The problem is that I can't make my brain come up with the equation required.

I suspect the equation is a simple division followed by a simple subtraction, but it's breaking my brain trying to come up with it. Please help. Thanks in advance.